# How To Send Form With HTML and Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

How do I send a form in this code with HTML and GS? It doesn't send when I click 'Submit'. I think there is an error with the 'send()' function, or maybe the form has errors. Please leave an answer. Thanks in advance!

---

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Quiz By Yona Klatchko -->
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p class="BoldVerdana">
      Welcome to Yona's Geography Quiz.
    </p>
    <p class="BoldVerdana">
      Begin whenever you are ready. 
    </p>
    <br/>
    <script>
     function send() {
         var emailAddress = document.getElementById('emailAddress').value;
         var result = document.getElementById('Questions').value;
         google.script.run.send(emailAddress, result);
     }
    </script>
    <style>
      p.BoldVerdana {
          font-weight: bold;
          font-family: "Verdana";
      }
    </style>
    <br/>
    <font face="Verdana">
      Your teacher's email address
    </font>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="name" id="emailAddress"/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div id="answers">
      <form name="Questions" id="Questions" method="post" action="EmailAddress; subject=Geography Quiz Answers enctype='text/plain'">
        <p class="BoldVerdana">
          Input questions
        </p>
        <font face="Verdana">
          1. Which state has a climate suitable for growing citrus fruits — California or Maine?
        </font>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input type="text" id="Ia1">
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <font face="Verdana">
          2. The North Atlantic current brings warm waters from the tropics to the west coast of which continent?
        </font>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input type="text" id="Ia2">
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <font face="Verdana">
          3. Which Canadian province produces more than half of the country's manufactured goods?
        </font>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input type="text" id="Ia3">
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <font face="Verdana">
          4. To visit the ruins of Persepolis, an ancient ceremonial capital of Persia, you would have to travel to what present-day country?
        </font>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input type="text" id="Ia4">
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <font face="Verdana">
          5. What is the term for a part of an ocean or sea that cuts far into the bordering landmass and may contain one or more bays?
        </font>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input type="text" id="Ia5">
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <p class="BoldVerdana">
          Multiple choice
        </p>
        <font face="Verdana" id="Ma1">
          6. Which one of the following zones of the atmosphere is rich in Ozone gas?
          <br/>
          <input type="radio" name="6. Which one of the following zones of the atmosphere is rich in Ozone gas?" value="Mesosphere">
          Mesosphere
          <br/>
          <input type="radio" name="6. Which one of the following zones of the atmosphere is rich in Ozone gas?" value="Troposphere">
          Troposphere
          <br/>
          <input type="radio" name="6. Which one of the following zones of the atmosphere is rich in Ozone gas?" value="Ionosphere">
          Ionosphere
          <br/>
          <input type="radio" name="6. Which one of the following zones of the atmosphere is rich in Ozone gas?" value="Stratosphere">
          Heat is generated in it
    <br/>
    <br/>
  </font>
        <font face="Verdana" id="Ma2">
          7. Troposphere is the hottest part of the atmosphere because
          <br/>
          <input type="radio" name="7. Troposphere is the hottest part of the atmosphere because" value="It is closest to the sun">
          It is closest to the sun
          <br/>
          <input type="radio" name="7. Troposphere is the hottest part of the atmosphere because" value="It is heated by the Earth's surface">
          It is heated by the Earth's surface
          <br/>
          <input type="radio" name="7. Troposphere is the hottest part of the atmosphere because" value="There are charged particles in it">
          There are charged particles in it
          <br/>
          <input type="radio" name="7. Troposphere is the hottest part of the atmosphere because" value="Heat is generated in it">
          Heat is generated in it
    <br/>
    <br/>
        </font>
        <font face="Verdana" id="Ma3">
          8. Continents have drifted apart because of
          <br/>
          <input type="radio" name="8. Continents have drifted apart because of" value="Volcanic eruption">
          Volcanic eruption
          <br/>
          <input type="radio" name="8. Continents have drifted apart because of" value="Folding and Faulting of rocks">
          Folding and Faulting of rocks
          <br/>
          <input type="radio" name="8. Continents have drifted apart because of" value="Tectonic activities">
          Tectonic activities
          <br/>
          <input type="radio" name="8. Continents have drifted apart because of" value="All of the above">
          All of the above
          <br/>
        </font>
        <br/>
      </form>
    </div>
    <button onclick="send(); Submit" value="Submit">
      <font face="Verdana" size="10">
        Submit
      </font>
    </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

GS:

---

Send():

```
function send(emailAddress, result) {
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, result)
}
```

---

doGet:

```
function doGet() {
    return(HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Quiz.html').evaluate().setTitle('Geo Quiz').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)); 
}
```

Comment: Well firstly use the developer tools of your browser to inspect the code and see what errors pop up in the console. Not sure why your on click attribute is "send(); Submit", should probably take out the Submit part

Answer (score 1):

Two parameters can't be sent to the server.  You have:

```
google.script.run.send(emailAddress, result);
```

Should be:

```
google.script.run.send([emailAddress, result]);//Put variables into an array
```

You should not name a `method` or `action` attribute in the `<form>` tag if you are going to use `google.script.run.myFunctionName()`.

You have:

```
<form name="Questions" id="Questions" method="post" action="EmailAddress; subject=Geography Quiz Answers enctype='text/plain'">
```

Should be:

```
<form id="Questions">
```

Also, you don't need a `name` attribute in the form element tag.  You are getting the form object by ID, which is what you should be doing.

If you want to get the entire `form` object, and sent the `form` object to the server, you should not use the `value` property.

You have:

```
var result = document.getElementById('Questions').value;
```

Should be:

```
var result = document.getElementById('Questions');//Get the Form object
```

If the email input field were inside of the form, then you could get the entire `form` object, and you wouldn't need to get the email address individually.  You have:

```
var emailAddress = document.getElementById('emailAddress').value;
```

If you do want the email address input field outside of the form object, then I explain how to do that at the end.

If you are going to send the form object, then every `<input>` must have a `name` attribute.  You don't have name attributes in all of you form input elements.

When Apps Script sends the form object to the server, it first processes the object and strips out everything except the `name` attribute as the key, and the value as the value in the key/value element of the object.  You can not get values out of the form object in the server by the id name.

You have `Submit` in the `<button>` element:

```
<button onclick="send(); Submit" value="Submit">
```

It should be:

```
<button onclick="send()">
```

You don't need a `value` attribute, because the word "Submit" is in between the two `button` tags.

The server function can not receive two parameters. You have:

```
function send(emailAddress, result) {
```

Should be:

```
function send(theFormObject) {
```

The server function should be:

```
function send(theFormObject) {
  MailApp.sendEmail(theFormObject.nameOfInput, result)
}
```

You are using very long names in the `name` attribute:

You have:

```
<input type="radio" name="6. Which one of the following zones of the atmosphere is rich in Ozone gas?" value="Mesosphere">
```

It seems like what you want is either a `placeholder` or an input label.

```
<input type="radio" placeholder="6. Which one of the following zones of the atmosphere is rich in Ozone gas?" value="Mesosphere">
```

Or:

```
<label for="questionSix">6. Which one of the following zones of the atmosphere is rich in Ozone gas?</label>
<input type="radio" value="Mesosphere" id="questionSix">
```

If you don't want to put the email input field inside of the `<form>`, then there is a problem, because you can't sent two separate values to the server.  You can however stringify the form object:

```
var result = document.getElementById('Questions');//The Form object
var myFormObject = JSON.stringify(result);
var emailAddress = document.getElementById('emailAddress').value;
```

And then send one long string to the server:

```
var bothEmailAndOjbect = emailAddress + "," + myFormObject;
google.script.run.send(bothEmailAndOjbect);
```